# fieldValue.increment(int) does not decrement the value in firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, increment

trying to decrement a value in firestore. but the below method does not work.

```
int fastDur = -20;

void cancelHours() async {
  return usersRef.doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).collection('posts')
    .orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
    .limit(1).get().then((querySnapshot) {
  return querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
    usersRef
        .doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).collection('posts')
        .doc(element.reference.id)
        .update({"totalTime": FieldValue.increment(fastDur)});
    });
  });
 }
```

however, if I put '-20' into the method FieldValue.increment(-20) then it works. But as you all know, I cannot hardcode it as the fastDur has different values that user chooses. please, help.

Comment: We can't see what's going on here, and need debugging information.  Maybe you could log the value of fastDur just before you use it, so that you know for certain that it contains the value you expect?  Also note that you are not handing errors with the call to update here, so something could be going wrong and you'd never know.

Comment: thank you, Doug! Went through log and it is 'Null check operator used on a null value'... I set the values in the widget with setState() on a button press. If then user decides to cancel I call an alertDialog, asking user "sure cancel the time?", if the user clicks ok, then the above method is fired...  why and where is the value lost? am new to flutter and coding...

Comment: Your question should illustrate everything you just said so that we can follow along and reproduce the behavior on our own.  Please read about [how to create a minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Including a reproducible example must be your next step as Doug commented. I could not reproduce your error with the snippet you included in the question. On my test, `FieldValue.increment()` did reduce a field without using a hard coded value. You can use [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#updating-documents) documentation to also get familiar with Flutter and Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Firestore buildin query method**

```
await _firestore.collection("Customers").doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection("Cart").doc(productid).update({
    'Quantity': FieldValue.increment(-1),
  })
```